# Android Settings->Scheduled power on & off set programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-settings

Some Android devices have the feature to turn off/on the device in the Settings application. Is it possible to set the on or off schedule programmatically? Is there an intent that can be accessed? In a more generic sense, how can you find out what intents are available to the Android programmer?

Comment: Are there an intent which allow to show power schedule settings ?